# Mobile app distribution

Tags: testing, cordova

I'm looking for a simple solution to distribute a cordova/phonegap app, which is under development, to all testing devices.

My current idea is to check on startup if there is a new version and download all files to the phone. Since PhoneGap apps are just HTML+JS+CSS ( except native plugins ), it should be possible to replace the www content of the app.

My question
Is there already a solution that supports this out of the box? (I did not find anything on google yet)

Is there a better approach? (It should be simple and cheap)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your needs 100% but I will give it a try.

My fav platform for beta mobile apps distribution is by far Testflight.
Support both android and IOS and free. Besides is pretty neat and simple.

Just prepare your app upload it to the platform and notify your users or testers that a new version is available. Then just dpwnload the new version.

As alternative you can use ftp for android to access and download the app or similar platforms like testflight.

## Private App distribution platforms

There are several options out there to create a private distrib. platform.

You can DIY using your fav. web techonologies, for android you just need to upload the apk and for ios could be a bit more tricky but you need the ipa signed according to the needs.

Also check this ones that could be the ones you need:

- AppSendr: https://www.appsendr.com/#gem
- Hockeyit: http://hockeykit.net/

Comment: Yes, something like this but i needs to run on your own servers

Comment: Edited my answer to point you to some additional resources that could be installed on the server-side.